# Selecting available parent items for article excluding sub items

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table of articles (tree of articles). Let's say it has id, parent_id and name.

[image]

For editing form of article I want to get list of available parent texts. I can't just list all texts because article can't be sub item of it's own sub item.

Is there any way to get that list using MySQL?

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected result

Comment: You can write condition in your query like `parent_id = null` or `parent_id = 0`

Comment: parent_id = 0 will give me just first level of article tree. I want all levels just without sub branch of current item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id NOT IN (

SELECT DISTINCT articles.id FROM
(
    SELECT
        @row_num := @row_num + 1 AS row_num, 
        IF(@last_id <> my_list.id, @id := my_list.id, @id) AS path_id,
        @last_id := my_list.id AS id,
        @id := (SELECT DISTINCT parent_id FROM articles WHERE id = @id) AS parent_id
    FROM
        (SELECT @id := 0, @last_id := 0, @row_num := 0) AS vars,
        (SELECT id FROM articles) AS my_loop,
        (SELECT id FROM articles) AS my_list
) AS t

INNER JOIN articles 
ON t.id = articles.id 
WHERE path_id = :id
)
```